# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #1](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/election/1) on The Great Outdoors has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: Willeke]

[image: WedaPashi]

[image: Rory Alsop]

Since this was your "graduation" election, these are now your inaugural "full" moderators — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes! And let's also thank the pro-tem mods who helped this site go through it's Beta phase!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/election/1) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5438312878702592).

Answer (score 5):

Congratulations to our new moderators: **Rory Alsop**, **WedaPashi**, and **Willeke**.

I also wish to thank all who ran in this election as well as all those who participated in it.

Bravo to you all!

Answer (score 5):

Congratulations Rory Alsop, WedaPashi, and Willeke!

Happy moderating :)

Answer (score 4):

There is a lot of common sense in our new trio of moderators.  And we had a great slate of candidates.  Thanks to all who ran.

Comment: Thanks. I hope I can proof worthy of your opinion.